# How to get hooked package version in Xposed?

Tags: android, xposed

How can I obtain the package's `versionName` and `versionCode` within the `IXposedHookLoadPackage.handleLoadPackage` function, before the app has been initialized? I have tried using `AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication()`, but it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use (idea from [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=53749075&postcount=8)). It returns a string in the format `versionName (versionCode)`.

```
private static String getPackageVersion(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) {
    try {
        Class<?> parserCls = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.content.pm.PackageParser", lpparam.classLoader);
        Object parser = parserCls.newInstance();
        File apkPath = new File(lpparam.appInfo.sourceDir);
        Object pkg = XposedHelpers.callMethod(parser, "parsePackage", apkPath, 0);
        String versionName = (String)XposedHelpers.getObjectField(pkg, "mVersionName");
        int versionCode = XposedHelpers.getIntField(pkg, "mVersionCode");
        return String.format("%s (%d)", versionName, versionCode);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        return "(unknown)";
    }
}
```